# Search a string in string array in android

Tags: java, android, string

I want to make an intelligent search as in **mobile contact** search in android.

e.g:
      When the user starts input in search box, after typing one alphabet, as a result, it should display all the data starting from the alphabet that was input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EditText searchTo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.medittext);
searchTo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//here you check for your conditions...

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        doSomething();



    } 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into the [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) provided by Android

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1. use AutoCompleteTextView
2. use textwatcher for EditText

check [Buttons on List View with easy searching in Android](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/buttons-on-list-view-with-easy-searching-in-android/)